# Construct a scatterplot of the selling price against the living area for the two groups

Tags: r

It is a homework project on R. The professor tho never explained anything, just gave us the sample codes. I can not get this plot with two different values for the factor living area. And I don't really understand why the interaction term is included.

"Construct a scatterplot of the selling price against the living area for the two groups:
Central Air = 1 and = 0. Explain why the interaction term is included."

I'm working with the Multiple regression model including the living area, “Central Air” (an indicator
variable coded as 1 if a house has central air conditioning, 0 otherwise), and their interaction. I am predicting the price. I did everything from my project but I have no idea how to plot this.

```
 m2<-lm(Price~Living.Area+Central.Air+Living.Area*Central.Air,data=hp)

 summary(m2);
```

## Plots below are the ones I tried

```
plot(Price~Living.Area,data=hp,col="red",Central.Air=1,xlab="Living Area",ylab="Price");

plot(Price~Living.Area,data=hp,col="blue",Central.Air=0,xlab="Living Area",ylab="Price");
```

I don't expect anything, I do not know how it should look like.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
living.area <- rnorm(n=100, 2, .5)
group = sample(rep(c(1,2), times = 50), size = 100, replace = FALSE)
#simulate an interaction
Price <- 10 + group*living.area + rnorm(n = 100, 0, 1)
data <- data.frame(list(Price = Price, 
                        Living_Area = living.area,
                        Air = group))
head(data)
Price Living_Area Air
1 12.02447    2.200390   1
2 12.70794    1.843377   1
3 14.56353    1.985669   2
4 14.68870    2.039686   2
5 12.35291    1.165078   2
6 13.52741    2.228445   2
```

## Here's to plot it

```
plot(data$Living_Area ,data$Price, col = data$Air+1)
abline(lm(Price ~ Living_Area, data = data[data$Air == 1,]),col=2,lwd=3)
abline(lm(Price ~ Living_Area, data = data[data$Air == 2,]),col=3,lwd=3)
abline(lm(Price ~ Living_Area, data = data),lty = 2)
```

[image]